# Can't read in files of a Folder using os.listdir

Tags: macos, python-3.x

I am unable to read in a list of files (currently in a Folder) using os.listdir

When I checked the pathnames, it looks correct and it points to the right folder as I can execute the variable name and it returns the exact list.

What could the issue be ?

```
import os
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")

INPUT_FOLDER = 'files/'
names = os.listdir(INPUT_FOLDER)
names.sort()

gen = get_batches(patients)

NotADirectoryError: [Errno 20] Not a directory:
```

Comment: That code can't work (where did the `patients` variable come from?). `os.listdir` does not include the directory name on returned files. If you want to use them as file names, you have to add that yourself. Perhaps `names = [os.path.join(INPUT_FOLDER, name) for name in os.listdir(INPUT_FOLDER)]` is what you want.

Comment: It should be easy to post a working example of the problem. For instance, just try `os.path.isfile(name)` instead of whatever that `get_batches` thing is. Minimal and complete examples are valued here.

Comment: I have managed to solve this issue by changing my folder directory and fixing the syntax. It was an error that I made earlier. Thanks for your help.